# Open Windows 7 "Map Network Drive" Dialog programmatically

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I am trying to open the dialog which is manually accessible through "Computer > Map Network Drive" on Windows 7. Is there any programmatic way to open it directly, e.g. with VBScript or PowerShell commands (not by firing mouse or keyboard events)? I am aware of `net use ...` shell command, but I specifically want to display that dialog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use rundll32.exe to pop the GUI from a script.  It behaves just as if you clicked the button.

```
RUNDLL32 SHELL32.DLL,SHHelpShortcuts_RunDLL Connect
```

[image]

Link included for additional tricks.   Map Network Drive is #24 on the list.

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/rundll.php

Answer (score 4):

Try WNetConnectionDialog:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

or WNetConnectionDialog1:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385436%28v=vs.85%29.aspx